# Change Home Directory Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, directory, home-directory

I'm trying to change the home directory to a different folder and my OS is not letting me do that. In Ubuntu I try to edit the useradd file but I can't figure out any way to save my changes that I made. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 12):

As root

```
usermod -d /path/to/new/directory username
```

Make sure your have created the new directory first with the mkdir command.
Then login as yourself again, the directory is set during login.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo usermod -d /path/to/new/home -m username
```

Comment: I get a  "user is currently used by process 2212" error. I have not been able to figure out what that process is.

Comment: reboot, try     sudo su and try above command