# My root directory is /home/username, how to revert to /root

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

When I open my terminal in Ubuntu and enter `ls`, it shows

```
Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public     Videos
Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates
```

This really confuses me. Because it should be root file like this:

```
bin    dev   initrd.img  lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
boot   etc   lib         media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib64       mnt         root  srv   usr
```

I do not know what happens here and how to convert to root directory. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I change my home directory"... or something else?

Comment: @TomHale Sorry I do not make it clear. The first directory is not what I want  to see when I open the terminal and type "ls". It is caused by some unknown operation so I just want to make everything back to the second one.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619737/change-home-directory-ubuntu-14-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are currently in home directory. try cd-ing to root directory with:

```
$ cd /
```

To show your current working directory, type

```
$ pwd
```

Comment: I know. But every time I start terminal, I was in /home/username directory. But it should not be this directory. Several days ago, the initial root directory is the directory which contains /use

Comment: you can change the default directory when starting terminal by adding `cd /` in your ` ~/.bashrc`